# Java application-context Hibernate Eclipse dtd error

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, applicationcontext

i have my `applicationContext-Hibernate something like this.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and suddenly appears a error that says..
[image: The error.]

i open the problems perspective and i see the problem right click show details and shows.

[image: eclipse errror.]

the line 81 is a empty line.

this error is quite annoying what can i do thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

1.Please try to clean,rebuild your project and than check for the error.

2.If still problem persists clean+restart your eclipse.

3.`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Change the `version="1.1"`

I had similar issue and able to solve by cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error description, it seems as if you have forgotten to close at tag properly. Try and look through your xml document, and scout for any missing ">"'s. If you want to be 100% percent sure, make a little program that counts the number of "<"'s and ">"'s in the file. If the amount of those signs aren't equal, you can conclude that you have an unclosed tag. Hope this helps.